Nix: which Haskell packages do you get in a nixpkgs version?
I'd like to figure out exactly which versions of Haskell packages get selected for a given nixpkgs version. I'm interested so I know which documentation version to look at, can set version constraints in the .cabal file, see why stuff breaks when promoting the nixpkgs version, etc.
I'm mainly looking at nixpkgs 22.11 cos that's what our code last worked in. I cloned Nixos/nixpkgs from github and checked out that branch. Soon I found  pkgs/development/haskell-modules/hackage-packages.nix with lots of packages named as Haskell names them, but there's no "base", only a "base_4_17_0_0", and as well as "aeson" there's "aeson_1_5_6_0" and "aeson_2_1_1_0".
From that I conclude that somewhere there must be a mapping from Haskell's names like "base" and "aeson" to something in that source file. But where? Grepping for "base_4_17_0_0" yields only that one match.
I also found out that Cabal2nix spits out a recipe that inputs things called "base" and "aeson" and indirectly passes them to mkDerivation. I thought mkDerivation was too general to know about Haskell in particular, so where could this mapping possibly be?

Boot libraries like base are tied to GHC versions; see this table for the mapping. Things like haskellPackages.base are set to null because they are provided by GHC. To figure out which GHC version is in nixpkgs, you can just build it or look at the definition for haskellPackages or ghc in pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix.
The mkDerivation we use for Haskell isn't the generic one, it's the one defined in pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix.
P.S.: I suspect that the intersection of {people who watch Stack Overflow questions} and {people who know how the Haskell infrastructure in nixpkgs works} is exactly me, so in the future I'd recommend asking in #haskell:nixos.org.

Thanks Naim!
Knowing that, I came up this this procedure:
Get the versions that nix bakes into a particular ghc version:

  git clone https://gitlab.haskell.org/bgamari/ghc-utils.git  

  cat <that repo's library-versions/versions/8.10.7.json (where 8.10.7 is a ghc version)>
    | jq '.packages | map({(.name): {haskellName: .name, version: .version}}) | add' > baseVersions.json

Get the rest of the versions: 

  Run this with desired nixpkgs in place of "23.11":

    nix repl --expr 'import (builtins.fetchTarball https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/refs/heads/nixos-23.11.tar.gz) {system="x86_64-linux";}'
  
    In there, say:
      with builtins; pkgs.writeText "foo" (toJSON (let hp = haskellPackages; in concatMap (n: let p = getAttr n hp; in if isNull p || isFunction p || isBool p || ! (hasAttr "pname" p) then [] else [{nixName=n; haskellName=getAttr "pname" p; version=getAttr "version" p;}] ) (attrNames haskellPackages)))
    and note the nix store path it returns.
 
  Call "nix-build <that path>".
  
  Say "cat result | jq ." to check.
 
  cat result | jq 'map({(.nixName): {haskellName: .haskellName, version: .version}}) | add' > otherVersions.json

Form the json union of the above two sources:

  jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' baseVersions.json otherVersions.json > allVersions.json

I don't know about anyone else but I think that was unreasonably difficult when all you want to know is which versions of packages you get. That strikes me as a pretty essential use case.
Is there an easier way? Could an easier way be implemented? Does flakes provide anything?
I'm also concerned about merging data from a particular nixpkgs version with data from a particular ghc version. That seems built to break.

I don't think it's unreasonable. Knowing what version of a package you get is easy: you just evaluate it and look at the store path (or the version attribute). What you want is to programmatically generate a mapping of package names to versions, and this just doesn't match the way things are structured in nixpkgs: some packages are bundled with GHC, some come from Hackage (see pkgs/data/misc/hackage/pin.json), and then we have overrides on top of that for Stackage and a bunch of manual overrides.
